# What does if [ $? -eq 0 ] mean for shell scripts?

Tags: bash, shell

There is this line in a shell script i have seen:

```
grep -e ERROR ${LOG_DIR_PATH}/${LOG_NAME}  > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
```

Comment: thanks Wyzard and Chris, great answers, however i may only select one  answer. ><

Comment: This question was asked and answered on August 18, 2011, but is being closed as being similar to a question asked and answered on August 30, 2011. Why are we allowing this o_o. Please upvote to keep this Open

Comment: Is there any good reason to keep this open, like: is there any difference to the other question?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It's checking the return value (`$?`) of `grep`. In this case it's comparing it to 0 (success).

Usually when you see something like this (checking the return value of grep) it's checking to see whether the particular string was detected. Although the redirect to `/dev/null` isn't necessary, the same thing can be accomplished using `-q`.

Comment: One question, where is /dev/null and what is it? Is it a file?

Comment: `/dev/null` is a kind of special "black hole" file. When you write to it, the data is thrown away. It's a classic way of stopping a program from printing its output to the screen.

Comment: To add to @Chris comment, `/dev/null` means "null device". When I think about what `/dev/null` actually is, it doesn't seem like such a great choice for a username.

Answer (score 47):

`$?` is the exit status of the most recently-executed command; by convention, 0 means success and anything else indicates failure.  That line is testing whether the `grep` command succeeded.

The `grep` manpage states:

> The exit status is 0 if selected lines are found, and 1 if  not  found.  If an error occurred the exit status is 2.  (Note: POSIX error handling code should check for '2' or greater.)

So in this case it's checking whether any ERROR lines were found.

Answer (score 4):

It is an extremely overused way to check for the success/failure of a command.  Typically, the code snippet you give would be refactored as:

```
if grep -e ERROR ${LOG_DIR_PATH}/${LOG_NAME} > /dev/null; then
   ...
fi
```

(Although you can use 'grep -q' in some instances instead of redirecting to /dev/null, doing so is not portable.  Many implementations of grep do not support the -q option, so your script may fail if you use it.)