# what does '$?' mean in a shell script?

Tags: shell, unix

I came across a shell script that contains a statement like,

```
if [ $val -eq $? ]
```

What does `$?` mean here?

Comment: [here is your answer][1] which may match to you question  


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101995/what-does-if-eq-0-mean-for-shell-scripts?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the special dollar sign shell variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163144/what-are-the-special-dollar-sign-shell-variables)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the special dollar sign shell variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5163144/608639)

Comment: https://swcarpentry.github.io/shell-novice/reference/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
$?
```

returns the status of the last finished command.
Status 0 tells you that everything finished ok.

In addition the `$` sign is a special symbol - and in that case `$val` extract the value that is hold by the variable `val`

Answer (score 26):

I found that the [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-special-variables.htm) is very useful and is the great answer. It includes clearly expression with sample.

[image]

Answer (score 17):

`$#` = number of arguments. Answer is `3`.

`$@` = what parameters were passed. Answer is `1 2 3`.

`$?` = was last command successful. Answer is `0` which means 'yes'.

Comment: Maybe it shouldn't bother me, but the fact that "0 == True" really grinds my gears.

Answer (score 3):

> > What does $? mean here?

$? is the last result of an exit-status ... 0 is by default "successfull"

```
bash# ls *.*
bash# echo $? 
bash# 0
bash# ls /tmp/not/existing/
bash# echo $?
bash# 2
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the value of the exit status of the previous command. This is `0` in case of success.

Answer (score -1):

`ls *.*` or `ls` would produce the same result. Meaning show zero or more files with any extension in the current directory.

`echo $?` would display the exit status. If at least one file is displayed from the last command ,the exit status would be zero(success).

Comment: Not exactly correct: `ls *.*` will filter the content of current directory and show only file and directories with period in them; for directories it will show the content (might depend on implementation). Also look at the following command `mkdir test && cd test && ls; echo "$?"` will return 0. However, `mkdir -m -r wo_dir && cd wo_dir && echo "test" > 1.txt && ls; echo "$?"` will return 1, with message `ls: .: Permission denied` even though the file is created.