# What does $? mean in shell scripting?

Tags: shell, unix

I encountered $? in one of the shell scripts I work on integrating (not written by me).

Just wanted to confirm that it means the return code of the previous command.

The usage is something like

```
runSomeCommand $VAR1 $VAR2 $VAR3

processResult $?
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [what does '$?' mean in a shell script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741710/what-does-mean-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: You can see the [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-special-variables.htm) Or my answers is in http://stackoverflow.com/a/26866587/1920536

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$?` is the exit status of the last executed command.

```
ls
....
echo $?
0

$ ls notexistingfile
ls: cannot access notexistingfile: No such file or directory

echo $?
2
```

Comment: thanks, that is what my assumption was that i wanted to confirm